# Test fails due to NSAssert assertion failure

Tags: objective-c, ocunit

I've just started writing tests for my iOS app, I'm using Xcode4 and OCUnit. I'm now writing a test for a piece of code that should throw an exception if a static variable has already been assigned to, like this:

```
NSAssert(controllerInstance == nil, @"another controller is already in use!");
```

In my test I use `STAssertThrows` to check that the above code throws an error if the instance already exists. The problem is that this test fails with:

```
*** Assertion failure in (reference to row with NSAssert)
```

So the test is failing even though the behavior is exactly the one I want. But shouldn't `STAssertThrows` catch this? Maybe I shouldn't use NSAssert together with `STAssertThrows` in this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the [assertion handler](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000055-BCIJBHDC) prints that message **before** raising the exception.  If that's not it, `STAssertThrows()` probably ignores assertion failures.

In any case, why are you testing that NSAssert works?  Do you not trust the Cocoa framework?

**Edit**

Just noticed the second part to your question.  The answer is no, you should not be using STAssertThrows and NSAssert together in this way.  `NSAssert()` is there to pick up cases of programming error where an assumption of the programmer is false.  By definition, a piece of code that asserts has failed its test case.

Comment: Alright, point taken. Then I wont use NSAssert in this case as I would rather gather the assumptions about how the code should work in my test cases.